# If condition based query in laravel

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, laravel-5

I have a query as:

```
 $Category = DB::table('food')
    ->select('food.Food_id','food.FoodName','categories.CategoryName')
    ->join('categories','categories.Category_id','=','food.Category_id')
    ->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Breakfast')
    ->get();
```

But I want query based on if condition,meaning that if Category is Breakfast then only food items related to Breakfast are shown or IF Category is Lunch then only food items related to that category are shown.I am using `laravel 5.2`

Comment: It works for what you want, what is the problem?

Comment: The edit made by @Kusum contains errors, please undo it.

Comment: @mastazi May I know where I did any mistake ?

Comment: All the minus signs: `-` should be replaced with `->` and, since there are several chained methods, it's a good idea to start a new line before each `->`

Comment: @mastazi Now its correct.

Comment: @Kusum I'm sorry, it's still not correct. I hate to be a PITA, but at the same time maybe you shouldn't have edited if you are not familiar with the PHP syntax. As I said above, the new line should start before `->` not after it. In addition you should use indentation for all the lines which are part of the query (except the first line). See an example here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You don't have to make a query all at once. You can combine it through several steps. Until you perform `get()`, `find()` or something similar in the end, it won't return query results, but only kind of query builder object if I'm not wrong.

```
// You should probably send this as a method parameter so you can determine if you should get one, or the other category
$cat = 1;

$Category = DB::table('food')
    ->select('food.Food_id','food.FoodName','categories.CategoryName')
    ->join('categories','categories.Category_id','=','food.Category_id');
if($cat == 0){
    $Category = $Category->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Breakfast');    
}
if($cat == 1){
    $Category = $Category->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Lunch');
}
$Category = $Category->get();
```

Comment: It is true that you can break the query as shown, but in this case it seems silly because you can just do `[...]->where('categories.CategoryName', '=',$cat);` without any if statement

Comment: Sure, but this was as a general example since I don't know what could be a content of `$cat` variable. It could be an integer or whatever, and of course `switch` would be a better solution, but it's just to show of how it works :)

Comment: This query results me both food items of breakfast and lunch also.

Comment: Updated an answer. Try it now. You probably didn't define `$cat` variable I introduced to your example @MuhammadRamzan

Comment: It results me all food items from the database whether it is breakfast,lunch or dinner.

Comment: Your approach will end up with many requests to the database. That's always bad thing to do. It'll take a lot of server time.